# How to populate ul from external html using append

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I'd like to populate an existing list unordered list which already has 10+ li's.
I'd like to populate it with JS or jQuery from another HTML file containing li's

OR

I'd like to populate the ul with li's from commented HTML.

```
<div class="Lcatnav categorynavigation">
function write_list_item(){
    var items = document.getElemntById("Lcatnav categorynavigation");
```

Is this possible?

So far I'm trying to append the ul by using a function to get element by id (the ul) then append to said ul with a bunch of variables.  This isn't working too well!

Comment: What dou you mean by this is not working to well? Do you have any error message? How do you wish to load the items from another html file - are you using an ajax call to a webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML DOM you can get the list by name using

```
document.getElementById("myList");
```

You can set a variable equal to the element or work directly from it using the appendChild() method.

```
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(newListItem);
```

or

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
   list.appendChild(elements[i]);
```